# Migrating Android app from GCM to FCM Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am migrating an Android app from GCM to FCM.  It uses upstream messaging.

The latest documentation still says @gcm.googleapis.com.

Why isn't it necessary to change the upstream endpoint for FCM messaging?

```
FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
    .setMessageId(Integer.toString(messageId))
    .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
    .addData("my_action","SAY_HELLO")
    .build());
```